# Let A and B be two distinct points. Prove each of the following equalities. (a) ray AB ∪ ray BA = line AB (b) ray AB ∩ ray BA = line AB

Tags: proof-verification, noneuclidean-geometry

Let A and B be two distinct points. Prove each of the following equalities.

(a) ray AB ∪ ray BA = line AB

(b) ray AB ∩ ray BA = segment AB

def of ray AB: $segment\:AB\:∪\:\left\{Pε\:line\:AB:\:A\cdot B\cdot P\right\}\:where\:B\:is\:between\:A\:and\:P$

To start off the problem i would think i should point out that AεrayAB and AεrayBA and Bεray AB and BεrayBA

and by defintion of union, A and B ε in line AB?

this seems to simple and not logical enough. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: @Arthur yes, you are correct

Comment: Very often (not always, but _very often_), when you want to prove equality between two sets, there are two specific things you check. Do you know what two things I'm referring to?

Comment: If they are subsets of eachother both directions?

Comment: Exactly. Try that, and remember the definition of union and intersection. That's basically all there is to it.

Comment: what i don't understand is how to use the definitions of ray and segment and line in my proof to show the subsets. I think it's more the definitions that are confusing to me.